# How can I identify the current domain from these dns entries under domains._msdcs tree?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, msdcs

I hope everybody had a good July 4th!

Looking through my DNS entries, I see the following:

---

[image]

---

My questions are:

1. How do I identify which of these belongs to the current domain?
2. Is it safe to delete the rest of them or should I just leave them all alone? Is there any harm done in keeping them?
3. How are these ids generated?

The reason I'm asking these is because I have had to rebuild Active Directory on a domain controller a few times and have had to use the same name. What I've been left with is a single _ldap record of that domain controller inside the _tcp record for every one of those entries. I suspect that some of these are remnants of that process and I'm trying to cleanup stale records. I've tried scavenging but they persist.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those entries are for programmatic lookup of your domain controllers by processes which have and use the GUID.  This provides a consistent DNS location to point to, which is useful when, for instance, the name of the domain changes.

The entries there will match the `objectGUID` property on each of your domains, which you can check and compare via ADSI Edit (the domain root object contains this property, the top `DC` object when you connect to the default context).

Keep in mind that this container is for the entire forest; every domain in the tree has an entry in there.  If an entry matches none of your current domains, it's safe to delete.